# TimesTen: Cannot connect to TimesTen daemon

Tags: oracle, daemon, in-memory-database, timesten

I'm trying to create a prototype application using TimesTen insted of home written IMDB. When I install TimesTen, TimesTen Data Manager service is hosted and also few subdaemons and server. Everything seems fine, but ttDaemonAdmin refuse to connect to main daemon. When I kill the process from Task Manager I can run it with ttDaemonAdmin, but after that none command isn't working. Every time I get a "Unable to connect to daemon. Check daemon status", but it indicates that there is a daemon proces ("Daemon pid 3576 port 53396 instance tt1122_64").
Same thing happens when I try to run ttStatus and ttModInstall command, so I can't change port number or any other option.
What could be a problem? Is it possible that port is blocked or something? I'm logged as user with admin privileges, but timestend proces owner is SYSTEM. 
I tried every imaginable solution I could find in oracle documentation, but nothing seems to work. Please help!

Thanx in advance,

Nikola

Comment: I didn't mention, I'm using 64-bit Windows 7 Proffesional SP1, on a domain computer, but with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

try use you timesten install user.

```
ttisql "dsn= tt1122_64"
```

if you use network connect way.
use

```
ttisqlcs "dsn= tt1122_64"
```

try check
1. TNS_ADMIN 
2.ORACLE and timesten lib
3.sys.odbc.ini
4.tnsnames.ora